# Regex: How to match all occurrences of @something in a string

Tags: regex, email, expression

I need to find all occurences of a word prededed by the '@' character in this way: @soemthing.

example:

`string input = "@alias1 is my first email but @alias2.com and email@alias3 along with @alias4 are disabled"`

I only want to match @alias1 and @alias4 but not @alias.com, or email@alias3

Thanks

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Perl? Python? C#? Grep?

Comment: What language are you using?  It makes a difference!

Comment: Which characters ought to be valid in an alias? For example, is `@my_alias` allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work...

```
(?<=^|\s)@\w+(?=\s|$)
```

To explain, `(?<=^|\s)` is a positive lookbehind ensuring that you're either at the beginning of the string, or there's a character of whitespace preceding your match.  And then `(?=\s|$)` is a positive lookahead ensuring that the match is followed by either by whitespace, or the end of the string.

Comment: This answer is perfect. Unfortunately I could not vote it up as being new to the system, my reputation is still below limit. Thanks so much. It works like a charm!!

Comment: @user825654 - You're welcome.  And you may not be able to upvote, but I think you can accept this answer.  Just click the big check mark.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following regular expression:

```
/(?:^|\W)@[\w]+(?:\s|$)/
```

Comment: This will match `@@alias`, which may or may not be allowable for the OP.

Comment: Will also match `@this_alias`. Question is unclear, but it looks like underscores may not be an allowed match

Answer (score 1):

I would use this: `(?<=(^|\s))@[a-zA-Z]+(?=(\s|$))`

This regex says "@ followed by letters, but preceded by whitespace or start of line, and the next character is whitespace or end of line".

Although your example doesn't specify, if you are willing to accept underscore chars, eg @some_thing, then you can replace `[a-zA-Z]` with simply `\w`

Comment: I don't think lookaheads "keep it simple." ;P

Comment: fiar comment - removed "simple"

Comment: @The Mask... dude, I know. that's why I said replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\w` IF YOU ARE WILLING TO ACCEPT UNDERSCORE CHARACTERS AS WELL.

Comment: @The Mask and @Bohemian - `\w` is actually `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Depending on the engine/configuration, it also includes Unicode letters.

Comment: @Justin. I know. Perhaps you didn't actually READ my answer: *...if you are willing to accept underscore chars...*

Comment: @Bohemian - Dude. Chill. Take a step back. I read your answer and all the comments. What I was pointing out was that, **in addition** to `[a-zA-Z_]`, the `\w` class **also** matches numerals, and sometimes Unicode letters such as И, β, and Ø. Both you and @TheMask got this wrong, and it's a very important point.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:  <s>`\b@\w+\b`</s>

You didn't specify programming language, so I'm assuming C#.  I don't know however whether C# supports "\b".

EDIT:

I will adopt Justin's comment and suggest `\B@\w+(?=["'\s]|$)` instead.

Comment: Sorry to be snarky and unhelpful, but why did you assume one language and then give an answer that may not work in that language?  Why not just assume the language it works in?  That doesn't make sense...

Comment: `\b` won't work at the end, as it considers `this.that` to have a word boundary on the period.

Comment: `\b@\w+\b` will not match `@alias1` and it *will* match `email@alias3`.

Comment: You're not too wrongheaded in your thinking, you just need a better understanding of what `\b` does. `@` is a non-word character, so `foo@bar` would match `\b` on either side of the `@` symbol. You're actually *blocking* what you want to allow, and vice versa. `\B` at the beginning would be closer to what you want. Personally, I might go with `\B@\w+(?=["'\s]|$)`, or `(?<^|["'\s])@\w+(?=["'\s]|$)` if lookbehinds are available.

Answer (score -2):

Try with this regular expression:

```
@\w+
```

Comment: This will match @name.com = fail

Comment: still won't work. test it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html